# Catel override InitializeAsync

Tags: overriding, task, catel

If I override the InitializeAsync() method from ViewModelBase in catel and create a new task what do I have to return.

```
protected override Task InitializeAsync()
{
    var basetask = base.InitializeAsync();
    var myTask = Task.Run(() => { // run something very important } );

    return basetask;
    // or
    return myTask;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When multiple awaitable tasks are executed, use async and await.

```
protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    await base.InitializeAsync();
    await Task.Run(() => { // run something very important } );
}
```

Another option is to store all tasks and return Task.WhenAll.

Comment: That's the whole point of async await. If you don't use async, you have to return a task. If you use async, the .net compiler will automatically create a task and return it during compile time.